# Stop loading controls in a Wrap panel once it's "full"

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

In one of my previous apps I needed to add controls to a flowlayoutpanel in a winforms project dynamically, but I needed them to stop loading once there was no more room in the panel for them to fit.

To achieve this I wrote: https://github.com/LucasMoffitt/WordFiller/blob/master/WordFiller.Controls/WordLayoutPanel.cs

This basically just sets a property to false if an inbound control touches a rectangle I draw at the bottom of the panel.

While trying to replicate this behaviour in WPF I can't find any way in which I can force a WrapPanel to stop taking in controls if it's full.

I've attempted to override the Arrange and Measure methods but they only get called once all the controls have been added. I need to be able to stop the controls from being loaded at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up taking in some suggestions and arrived at this:

https://github.com/LucasMoffitt/CustomWrapPanel

basically it's what I was doing to begin with just a little tidier, and has a demo app.

I encourage all contributions if anyone finds a nicer way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

You could check `ActualHeight`/`AcxtualWidth` against `DesiredHeight`/`DesiredWidth`. When `DesiredHeight` becomes larger than `ActualHeight` - the panel began overlapping.

Comment: When would I check for it? I'd have to keep track of what's been added so far.

Comment: If you are adding controls dynamically, then you have some code for this, in between every addition, you should check the properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought about what you said and had a play around with some different approaches, see my answer below! Thanks again!